# python numpy/scipy find count or frequency of a relative variable in multi-dimensional array

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have a three dimensional array, say dat.shape = (100,128,256). I'm trying to count the number of periods that have values greater than 10.0 across the first axis. For example, for dat[:,0,0], how many times does a value greater than 10.0 occur? Then, dat[:,0,1] to dat[:,n,m]. My end matrix would have a shape of (128,156).

Is there a way to do this calculation in numpy or scipy without looping across the 1st and 2nd dimension?

Thank you very much!

Comment: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.sort.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
a = np.random.randint(0, 100, (100,128,256))
np.sum(a > 10, axis=0)
```

Comment: If I understood this, `sum` performs a total sum along an axis and, given that `a > 10` returns `bool` and in python true values are equal do one, then `sum` in this case is equivalent to counting, right?

Comment: Basically, but it will be far more efficient than writing a native for loop.